# AttachedProperty to an object?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, attached-properties

I used [this "guide"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx),
but the difference is that I don't want to restrict the object Im attaching the property on, to `UIElement`
I'd like to attach a property to the most generic item : object, so here is my code :

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty QbNameProperty =    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "QbName",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(QbName),
        new PropertyMetadata("")
    );

    public static void SetQbName(object obj, string name)
    {
        obj.SetValue(QbNameProperty, name);
    }
    public static Boolean GetQbName(object obj)
    {
        return (Boolean)obj.GetValue(QbNameProperty);
```

The thing is that SetValue and GetValue do not exist for object... I tried to look everywhere (SO and google) and didnt find any solution but as far as I understood the article I linked, attachedProperties are not restricted to UIElements right ?
So... what should I do ?

ps : to complete my answer I HAVE TO get a Name for some objects Im parsing from a DLL (and display it in a TreeView) so, if I don't have a Name fields/property, I'll add the attachment !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't attach properties to Object (or you'll be able to extend the whole framework..).
Dependency properties can only be used by objects inheriting from [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx).

```
/// <summary>
/// QbName
/// </summary>
public class QbName : DependencyObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Name",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(QbName),
        new PropertyMetadata("")
        );

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">The element.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    public static void SetName(DependencyObject element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(NameProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">The element.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetName(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return element.GetValue(NameProperty).ToString();
    }
}
```

Then you can use the static methods:

```
QbName qb = new QbName();
QbName.SetName(qb, "test");
```

Comment: Dependency properties can only be used by DependencyObjects, and QbName should inherit from that. But you can attach an attached property to any object.

Comment: We are saying the same thing. You can attach a dependency property to anything that derives from DependencyObject, NOT from (System.)Object.

Comment: This is from the article I linked : "If your class is defining the attached property strictly for use on other types, then the class does not have to derive from DependencyObject. But you do need to derive from DependencyObject if you follow the overall WPF model of having your attached property also be a dependency property."

Comment: The defining class does not have to drive from DependencyObject, but the type to which you are attaching the property has to (in your case 'QbName')

Comment: I got this "public class QbName : DependencyObject" but still dont get how to attach the prop :/ Can u give me a small snippet plz ?

Comment: @GuillaumeSlashy see my edits. Hope this helps, you can also have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx#attached_properties_code

Comment: Ok but in ur example, QbName is a UIElement. What Im looking for is the same thing on objects :/

Comment: @GuillaumeSlashy you can use DependencyObject in place of UIElement as the parameter for the static methods (re-edited)

Comment: ok for DependencyObject but my problem is on "generic" objects :( The quote I published 6 comments above makes me believe that it's possible !

Answer (score 0):

Dependency properties are not restricted to `UIElement`s, but they are restricted to [`DependencyObject`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx). If you change `object` in your code to `DependencyObject`, it should work.

I have no idea what are you actually trying to do, so I don't know if doing this is a feasible solution.

Comment: He's not using an usual dependency property, but an attached property.

Comment: This is from the article I linked : "If your class is defining the attached property strictly for use on other types, then the class does not have to derive from DependencyObject. But you do need to derive from DependencyObject if you follow the overall WPF model of having your attached property also be a dependency property."